# Magento Use Web Server Rewrites in Multi Domain Setup

Tags: magento

I have to two stores each having different domain. They are hosted on dedicated server with SuExec disabled. I have copied the .htaccess and index.php and everything works fine.

The problem I am having is with my 2nd store Web Server Rewrites. As soon I enabled this for the 2nd store which is using symbolic link to the root directory, it starts giving page not found error.

domain2.com/index.php/abc.html ----- Works Fine with Use Web Server Rewrites Turned Off

domain2.com/abc.html ----- Does not work with Use Web Server Rewrites Turned ON

The base store works without any problem.

Any help is much appreciated.

Farrukh Khan

Comment: The problem was with the .htaccess file. Once it was properly copied to the domain2 folder, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

-> **Flush The Magento Cache**

Goto System->Cache Management

Refresh the catalog rewrites

Goto All Cache and change drop down to Refresh.

Click save

On most server, this should take out the index.php in your URL’s.

If you are getting a 404 error, continue reading.

-> **Fixed Mode_Rewrite Errors**

- Please check you webserver configuration.
  Do you use Apache? Maybe there is something like "AllowOverride none" in your configuration which disables .htaccess-files (the .htaccess-file in your magento-root-directory defines the rewrite-rules).
  The most common cause for this is that you have an incorrect .htaccess file in your ftp.

Goto the magentocommerce.com site and download the magento files again.

Extract the files, and ONLY upload the .htaccess file to your Magento root directory.

This should fix any problems related to enabling the use of web server rewrites in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem above, but now i solved already. The main reason for that problem  is .htaccess file. By replacing .htaccess file with magento default .htaccess file solve all the problem. Web Server Rewrites Turned on or off, you can do as you like.

After saving the configuration, don't forget to clear cache.